# Kinematics problem regarding motion of a particle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

A particle of mass m moves on the $x$-axis as follows: it starts from rest at $t = 0$ from the point $x = 0$, and comes to rest at $t = 1$ at the point $x = 1$. No other information is available about its motion at intermediate times ( $0 < t < 1$).

If α denotes the magnitude of instantaneous acceleration of the particle, then which of the following is/are true?
(a) α cannot remain positive throughout
(b) α cannot exceed 2 at any point in its path
(c) α must be equal to 4 at some point or points in its path
(d) α must change sign during the motion, but no other assertion can be made with the information given

Obviously the a part is correct because the the particle has to deaccelerate to come to a stop.
i think one can do this by shm also but please give me the solution with the help of kinematics also. I dont understand why the c part is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is correct is you do not take into account the sign. Suppose that the acceleration were constant then $x=1/2 a t^2$, and to reach $x=1$ at $t=1$ then  $a=2$. Of course, in this example the mass did not stop, If it stops, it needs to descelerate. In the symmetrical case of constant accekeration and constant desceleration it is easy to see that the mass will need to accelerate on half of the time, so $a=4$ to get to the middle point in half a second and then $a=-4$ to make it stop. The same will happen if the motion is not uniform, a smaller acceleration forward for a longer time (let say a slightly larger than two until the last millisecond, must be compensated by a much larger desceleration at the last millisecond. Same for any other combination of acceleration/decelerations you could imagine, at some point either the acceleration of the deceleration must be at least 4.